# Display calendar in Jquery datepicker when user select something from select option where value is from database

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Hi can anyone help me with displaying calendar in jquery if user clicks on a certain option in dropdown list?
Here is my code

```
function OnChange(dropdown)
{
  var status = dropdown [dropdown.selectedIndex].text;
  status = dropdown[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  if (status == 01){
      $(function() {
         ("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+5M" });
        alert ("Success");
        });
  }
  return true;
}
```

**My Html**

```
<tr>
         <td>
         <select id="schedule" onchange="OnChange(this.form.schedule);" >
     //I used jquery here to get the value of select option from database and works ok
     //There is corresponsing value on the options. If 01, the calendar will be shown, the rest..it will not be shown


      </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to display a calendar beside the dropdown list if 01 is selected.
The problem in jquery is, it needs id before the calendar will display like #datepicker. I dont need additional textbox or anything, and after the date is selected..it will be displayed below the select field. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hbpv7/2/

I am currently adding a temp datepicker (inline) after the select, when you select value 01. And if you picked a date, the datepicker is removed and the new date is displayed.

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "yoururl.php",
        success : function(result){
            $("select").append(result);
        }
    });
    $("select").change(function(){
        if($(this).find("option:selected").text() == "01")
        {
            showDatepicker.call(this);
        }   
        else
        {
             $("#tmpdatepicker").remove();   
        }
    });
});

function showDatepicker()
{
    // Don't  show more then 1
    if($("#tmpdatepicker").length) return;

    $(this).after("<div id='tmpdatepicker'></div>");
    var _tmp = $("#tmpdatepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect : function(dateText, inst){
             $(this).after("<div class='mydate'>" + dateText + "</div>").remove();
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But when i select the "02" twice, it is displaying the date twice or more..and it did not display the data from  the database

Comment: Updated so only 1 calendar will be shown, but what will come from the database?

Comment: the values will be coming from database using GET..so the only html that i have is: <tr>
         <td>
         <select id="schedule" onchange="OnChange(this.form.schedule);" >
      </select>
    </td>
</tr>

Comment: If i select other option, the date doesnt disappear in your sample here  http://jsfiddle.net/Hbpv7/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+5M" }).hide();
$("#schedule").bind("change",function(){
  if ($(this).val() == 01)
     $("#datepicker").show();
  else
     $("#datepicker").hide();
});
```